# MySQL 'where case' apply only to some value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
id | date_inserted | type       | route_id | route_type | km
1    2016-01-05      Transport    null       Normal       null
2    2016-01-06      Transport    null       Normal       50
3    2016-01-07      Transport    1          Normal       null
4    2016-04-02      Transport    2          Normal       null
5    2016-05-03      Services     null       Normal       20
6    2016-06-21      Transport    null       Exceptional  35
```

And I needed to retrieve the total routes by months. That was accomplish by doing:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
      type IN ('Transport', 'Services')
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC
```

The output is something like:

```
type       | total | month
Transport    3       1
Transport    1       2
Services     1       5
Transport    1       6
```

And it works fine. However, now I was asked to apply some conditions only when the type is `Transport`, the conditions are the following:

1. The `route_id` must not be null OR
2. The `route_type` must be `Exceptional` OR
3. The `route_type` is `Normal` AND `km` is not equal to zero

So, according to this conditions, this is what I've tried:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
      type IN ('Transport', 'Services') AND 
      (CASE WHEN type = 'Transport' THEN 
            route_id IS NOT NULL OR
            route_type = 'Exceptional' OR 
            (route_type = 'Normal' AND km != 0)
      END)
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC
```

But my output is:

```
type       | total | month
Transport    2       1
Transport    1       2
Transport    1       6
```

The `Services` row is missing.

Comment: add an `ELSE` condition to the `CASE` statement that returns True...e.g. `CASE WHEN <...> ELSE 1 = 1 END`

Comment: your case will return null for `Services`. Handle it in another `When` or `else`

Comment: @PJSantoro Why not post this as an answer? The analysis and proposed solution are both correct.

Comment: Yea, guess I should've done that. I've been beat to it now, but all good. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an else segment to handle the services.  If you want the case to yes allow for normal processing use 1 = 1.

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
  type IN ('Transport', 'Services') AND 
  (CASE WHEN type = 'Transport' THEN 
        route_id IS NOT NULL OR
        route_type = 'Exceptional' OR 
        (route_type = 'Normal' AND km != 0)
  ELSE 
  1 = 1
  END)
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

As others says, you need to add an `ELSE` to your case, otherwise when the row is 'Service' it will return null and does not show the record.

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
      type IN ('Transport', 'Services') AND 
      (CASE WHEN type = 'Transport' THEN 
            route_id IS NOT NULL OR
            route_type = 'Exceptional' OR 
            (route_type = 'Normal' AND km != 0) 
            ELSE 1 = 1
      END)
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC;
```

Another version you can use (which I prefer) is:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
      (type = 'Services' OR 
            (type = 'Transport' and 
                    (route_id IS NOT NULL OR
                        route_type = 'Exceptional' OR 
                        (route_type = 'Normal' AND km != 0)
                    )
        )
      )
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC;
```

If `route_type` can only be `Normal` and `Exceptional` you can change the condition:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(id) AS `total`, MONTH(date_inserted) AS `month`
FROM routes
WHERE YEAR(date_inserted) = '2016' AND 
      (type = 'Services' OR 
            (type = 'Transport' and 
                    (route_id IS NOT NULL OR
                     route_type = 'Exceptional' OR 
                     km != 0
                    )
        )
      )
GROUP BY type, `month`
ORDER BY date_inserted ASC, `total` DESC;
```